# Gitlab DinD storing python test results

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

```
services:
  - docker:20.10.16-dind

build:
  image:
    name: {url to ecr image}
  script:
    - source ./build.sh
    - |
       mkdir -p /tmp/airport/
       docker cp airport:/artifacts /tmp/airport/
       ls /tmp/airport/
  
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: /tmp/airport/artifacts/nosetests.xml

  
  tags:
    - airportwait
```

I am working on this gitlab-ci.yml file, which is run on our own EC2 Gitlab runners. It is using DinD.

The `./build.sh` does a lot of work including

```
dc run --name "airport" airport \
            /bin/bash -xc "
                mkdir -p /artifacts && \
                py.test --junitxml=/artifacts/nosetests.xml \
                --cov=$project \
                --cov-report=html:/artifacts/coverage \
                /code/airport/tests"
```

The output of `ls /tmp/airport/` under script step of build shows the results file and coverage directory as expected.

```
coverage
nosetests.xml
```

However, the artifact step fails:

> Uploading artifacts...
> WARNING: /tmp/aviation/artifacts/nosetests.xml: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory
> ERROR: No files to upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path that you have specified for artifacts (/tmp/airport/artifacts/nosetests.xml) is not within the source checkout directory and so is invalid.
Take note of the error message:

> Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory

After the artifact file has been generated, you could copy the file to somewhere within the source checkout directory, e.g:

```
cp /tmp/airport/artifacts/nosetests.xml $CI_PROJECT_DIR/artifacts/nosetests.xml
```

and then reconfigure GitLab artifacts to that new location:

```
artifacts:
  when: always
  reports:
    junit: artifacts/nosetests.xml
```